# Input in between prints from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to ask the user to input f in order to print the next line from a .txt file.  So far i can only ask for 1 user input and it will either output the whole list or a specific line from the list.  I am just trying to print the lines in order with user input in order to continue.  Here's my code so far:

```
def wordDefinition():
    fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
    if fullList == 'f':
        with open('study_games.txt', 'r+') as f:
            print(f.readline())
```

Comment: Open the file before `fullList = input(...)` but this can only work once anyway because you don't have a `while` loop.

Comment: if I add the while loop then it just keeps running and only prints the first line of the .txt document.  This is where I'm confused because I cant get it to stop printing blank lines, and then I don't know how to get it to print the second line after the second f input.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

If you just want the user to keep `inputting` until an `f` where you then `print()` the first line, you can do the following:

```
def wordDefinition():
   with open('study_games.txt', 'r+') as f:
      fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
      while fullList != 'f':
         print("you didn't enter f!")
         fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
      print(f.readline())
```

It should be fairly clear what is going on here. We are simply asking the user for an `input` and `while` that `input` is *not* `'f'`, we print that they didn't enter `'f'` and ask for another `input`.

Once they do enter `'f'`, we print the first line using `f.readline()`.

### Option 2

However, I'm not sure that this is what you want. I think that you are not looking for the first line of the `txt` file, but really for the *`entire`* file to be be `printed` when the user `inputs` `'f'`.

This is really easy to do, we just switch the `f.readline()` to `f.read()`!

Making the code:

```
def wordDefinition():
   with open('study_games.txt', 'r+') as f:
      fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
      while fullList != 'f':
         print("you didn't enter f!")
         fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
      print(f.read())
```

The reason this will work to display the *whole* file is as follows. If we have a simple `txt` file for testing, let's call it `test.txt`, with the contents:

```
testing
line1
line2
line3
```

then when we call:

```
open("test.txt", "r").read()
```

we get back a `string` of the contents of the `txt` file with newline (`\n`) characters separating the lines:

```
"testing\nline1\nline2\nline3\n"
```

so we can pass this `string` directly into `print()` which will display the file just as it is seen in a text editor (new lines in place of the `'\n'` characters). So the call:

```
print(open("test.txt", "r").read())
```

will just give back the same as before:

```
testing
line1
line2
line3
```

so you can use the same idea to display the *entire* contents of `'f'`.

### Option 3

If you want to have the user input `'f'` and just one line print out and then wait for another input for the next line till the end of the file, you just need to put the first code in a `for loop`. You can loop over your file's lines really easily with a `for loop` which iterates over the file object.

So all we need to do, is add a `for loop` into the first `code`:

```
def wordDefinition():
   with open('study_games.txt', 'r+') as f:
      for line in f:
         fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
         while fullList != 'f':
            print("you didn't enter f!")
            fullList = input("press f for your list of words and definitions\n")
         print(line)
```

Comment: sorry i'm not good at writing what i mean.  what i need to do is when they hit f+enter, the first line is printed, then when they hit f + enter again the second is printed, and so on for however many lines are in the text file.

Comment: I have updated the answer (`option 3`) for the way you just explained. Please up vote and accept if it helps! **:)**